# Eclipse JSON editor error

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse, editor

All is in the message:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Expected value at 1:0
>   - mismatched input 'var' expecting {STRING, NUMBER, 'true', 'false', 'null', '[', '{'}

```
var jsonQuiz = '{
  "datum": "2012-02-28",
  "vragen": [{
      "vraag": "Welke film won de oscar voor beste buitenlandse film?",
      "antwoorden": ["Rundskop", "In Darkness", "A separation", "Footnote"],
      "correct": 2,
      "tekst": "A separation is de eerste Iraans film die een Oscar wint. De film gaat over een echtscheiding in het huidige Iran",
      "media": "oscar.jpg",
      "url": "http://oscar.go.com/"
    },
    {
      "vraag": "Wie won in 2011 de Ronde van Vlaanderen?",
      "antwoorden": ["Nick Nuyens", "Tom Boonen", "Philippe Gilbert", "Fabian Cancellara"],
      "correct": 0,
      "tekst": "In de sprint won Nuyens het van Chavanel en Cancellara, terwijl Boonen sterk kwam opzetten maar strandde op een vierde plaats",
      "url": "http://www.rondevanvlaanderen.be"
    },
    {
      "vraag": "De Belgische regeringsformatie brak alle vorige records qua duurtijd, na hoeveel dagen na de verkiezing was er een regering?",
      "antwoorden": [356, 485, 510, 541],
      "correct": 3,
      "tekst": "Deze formatie was de langstdurende formatie ooit in België en duurde 541 dagen. Het eerdere Belgische record van 194 dagen werd op 25 december 2010 verbroken"
    },
    {
      "vraag": "De winter 2011-2012 kende toch een lange vorstperiode met 14 opeenvolgende ijsdagen. De vorige winter, 2010-2011, kende in totaal hoeveel ijsdagen?",
      "antwoorden": [5, 8, 11, 15],
      "correct": 3,
      "tekst": "De laatste maand van 2010 was zeer koud met veel sneeuw. Te Ukkel bedroeg het aantal ijsdagen over de gehele winter 2010-2011 15 dagen.",
      "media": "ijs.jpg"
    },
    {
      "vraag": "In China is 2012 het jaar van",
      "antwoorden": ["het varken ", "de draak", "de slang", "de rat"],
      "correct": 1,
      "tekst": "2012 is het jaar van de draak. De mensen die in het jaar van de draak geboren zijn, zijn levendige mensen die to the point zijn. Ze zijn ook trots, vol enthousiasme en hebben zin in het leven.",
      "media": "china.jpg"
    }]
  }
';
```

Comment: Please mark your whole json as code in order for SO to format it right.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @AFI is your Question solved? If so please mark the answear as such. If not please add further Details to your Question so we can help you...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your json starts with a variable declaration. But json only represents the object. You must remove the `var jsonQuiz='` and immediately start with `{` and end with `}` without the `';`.

Answer (score 0):

but with a command on 1 line it is ok

jsonQuiz = '{"datum":"2012-02-28","vragen":[{"vraag":"Welke film won de oscar voor beste buitenlandse film?","antwoorden":["Rundskop","In Darkness","A separation","Footnote"],"correct":2,"tekst":"A separation is de eerste Iraans film die een Oscar wint. De film gaat over een echtscheiding in het huidige Iran","media":"oscar.jpg","url":"http://oscar.go.com/"},{"vraag":"Wie won in 2011 de Ronde van Vlaanderen?","antwoorden":["Nick Nuyens","Tom Boonen","Philippe Gilbert","Fabian Cancellara"],"correct":0,"tekst":"In de sprint won Nuyens het van Chavanel en Cancellara, terwijl Boonen sterk kwam opzetten maar strandde op een vierde plaats","url":"http://www.rondevanvlaanderen.be"},{"vraag":"De Belgische regeringsformatie brak alle vorige records qua duurtijd, na hoeveel dagen na de verkiezing was er een regering?","antwoorden":[356,485,510,541],"correct":3,"tekst":"Deze formatie was de langstdurende formatie ooit in België en duurde 541 dagen. Het eerdere Belgische record van 194 dagen werd op 25 december 2010 verbroken,"},{"vraag":"De winter 2011-2012 kende toch een lange vorstperiode met 14 opeenvolgende ijsdagen. De vorige winter, 2010-2011, kende in totaal hoeveel ijsdagen?","antwoorden":[5,8,11,15],"correct":3,"tekst":"De laatste maand van 2010 was zeer koud met veel sneeuw. Te Ukkel bedroeg het aantal ijsdagen over de gehele winter 2010-2011 15 dagen.","media":"ijs.jpg"},{"vraag":"In China is 2012 het jaar van","antwoorden":["het varken ","de draak","de slang","de rat"],"correct":1,"tekst":"2012 is het jaar van de draak. De mensen die in het jaar van de draak geboren zijn, zijn levendige mensen die to the point zijn. Ze zijn ook trots, vol enthousiasme en hebben zin in het leven.","media":"china.jpg"}]}';